# SonatajQueryBundle no longer installed as dependency

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

```
Fatal error: Class 'Sonata\jQueryBundle\SonatajQueryBundle' not found in /Users/.../app/AppKernel.php on line 21
```

I'm getting the above error after upgrading the SonataAdminBundle versions to dev-master in my [composer.json](https://gist.github.com/codecowboy/b783257e4c9762fb29b3) and doing a `composer update` in order to try the new Bootstrap3 layout.

Does this now have to be added manually as a dependency? It seems like the jquery bundle has now been removed as if I comment out line 21, the site loads but none of the jquery assets are loaded.

Comment: Have you done `php composer.phar update`?

Comment: yes. That's when the error started happening

Comment: Remove the line 21 in `AppKernel.php` and try again.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas thanks. I know what the error means, I'm trying to find out what has changed. Its likely to be related to the SonataAdminProject and their master branch being broken.

Comment: If you remove the definition in `AppKernel.php` and run `composer update`, composer will install your needed dependencies. You don't have to change `AppKernel.php` manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assets management has been improved in the upcoming stable version. The SonataAdminBundle now uses bower to handle assets (https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2036).

So if you update your code, you will need to remove SonatajQueryBundle. Also, there is a new configuration section to add your assets in the AdminBundle. So you can have a fine control on which assets are loaded in your project. (https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/configuration.rst).

Last point, if you have overwritten the default template, you might need to adjust it to properly load assets.

Comment: thanks! Would switching to SBAdmin2 be a simple matter of changing the config paths which reference AdminLTE or much more involved?